# string.Format problem in concatenating left-to-right languages with right-to-left languages

Tags: .net, string, formatting, right-to-left

Persian is a right-to-left language. I want to show a message to the user that something was saved successfully. However, the name of that thing (entity) is sometimes in English, and sometimes in Persian. Thus I should combine some Persian words with placeholders for English words as follow:

```
string.Format("مطلب {0} با موفقیت ذخیره شد", contentTitle);
```

Now, if we suppose that contentTitle is `How to solve your problem`, the concatenated string would be:

```
مطلب How to solve your problem با موفقیت ذخیره شد.
```

This is not what I want to get. The desirable result should be:

```
.با موفقیت ذخیره شد How to solve your problem مطلب
```

What should I do? It seems that `string.Format` method has problem in concatenating left-to-right languages with right-to-left languages. What I want to achieve is very similar to `direction: rtl;` in [CSS Writing](http://www.thoughtresults.com/css-writing).

Comment: is this a problem with string.Format() or with the rendering engine displaying the output?

Comment: I debugged the code, and this is the problem of `string.Format()`.

Answer (score 2):

the string class doesn't know anything about RTL and Windows has its own rules to deal with "mixed content" (that is rtl and ltr in one string)...

you can experiment with `LRO`, `LRE` etc. Unicode "hints" in those string to achieve desired result - see table at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-directional_text